# Python, pygraphviz, networkx

Tags: python, networkx, pygraphviz

I built a directed weighted graph using networkx and I can draw it, but it has very often crossed edges even if the graph is very small. I used pygraphviz also, but I was unable to add labels. Can someone help me with that ?

```
   edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
              for u,v,d in DG.edges(data=True)])
   pylab.figure(1)
   pos=nx.spring_layout(DG)

   nx.draw(DG, pos)
   nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(DG,pos,edge_labels=result,font_size=10)

   pylab.show()
```

How to convert it to pygraphviz graph and add labels to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graphviz draws the 'label' attribute on edges.  Here is an example of setting the label attribute to the edge weight if it exists.

```
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv # need pygraphviz or pydot for nx.to_agraph()

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=7)
G.add_edge(2,3,weight=8)
G.add_edge(3,4,weight=1)
G.add_edge(4,1,weight=11)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)

for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True):
    d['label'] = d.get('weight','')

A = nx.to_agraph(G)
A.layout(prog='dot')
A.draw('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to add labels later, because I calculate these values after I build this graph

Comment: I see it is possible to assign value after, thank you

Comment: Note: this function call is now `A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)`